# Create padded texture atlas with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I am using Imagemagick to create an offline texture atlas, using `composite` commands to add all the tiles to the atlas.

I want to avoid bleeding of the tiles between each other when using `GL_LINEAR`, so I want to add a border around each tile. As the tiles are not neccessarily tileable, I’d prefer to replicate the corresponding edge of the tile for creating the edge.

I am fine to do this conversion to the individual images before composing them together. The most important point is that it needs to be able to run from a Makefile.

I know that I can do this using composite with adequate cropping of the borders, but that would take lots of commands to write. Does ImageMagick have any such tool built in?